# On Inkscape - Can I take two objects of different color and link their paths such that they would auto smooth like a single path would?

Tags: inkscape

Normally I would use either Path>Combine or Path>Union to merge two objects in order to make a larger more complex shape. However, in this case I need both objects to keep their individual colors, while still having their paths merged. Is there a way to do this?

Pretty much I'm distorting the object (via it's paths taking advantage of auto smooth) and would like the distortion to affect the whole image but while keeping the distinct colors and characteristics of each area.

Comment: Hi. Any chance you could share an image showing what you are trying to achieve or what has failed. You can't apply auto smoothing once an object has been created, however there may be other ways to manipulate the objects afterwards - if only I knew what you have in mind, or what kind of "distortion" you mean. Thanks

Comment: I have a vectorised flag whose shape I'm manipulating, and I was hoping i could get one section of the flag to modify itself as I manipulate the section next to it. That way it could auto smooth between one section of the flag and another. However, I went a different way by making a template of the final shape and editing each section accordingly.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/133659/edit) and show or describe what kind of distortion you are trying to apply to the flag. Thanks.

Comment: Path is a single object and it can't have more than one property of each kind, meaning that you can't have different fills or strokes. If you'd show the flag, I could show you how to achieve the effect you want. In the early days of Wikimedia Commons I was learning Inkscape by vectorizing flags and coat of arms (user:krzysiu).